# How I know the number of each kind of record in the database?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have to do a program to check how many courses the students take in each kind of course. It is required that students who takes 9 from base courses, 20 or more from major courses and 2 from optional courses then I will calculate the number of students who register on my page to achieve the requirements.

I tried this code but it doesn't work:

```
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
 SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Select count(kind) From Courses inner join Sched on Courses.Id = Sched.SCourses inner join Students on Sched.Student_ID = Students.Student_Id where Courses.kind='Major' and Students.Student_Id ='"+TextBox1.Text+"' and Students.Exeded_houres = '120' ", con);

 SqlDataReader reader;
 try
 {
     con.Open();
     reader = com.ExecuteReader();
     while (reader.Read())
     {
        if (reader.HasRows == true)
        {
            Label3.Text = com.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            Label3.Text = "Students not graduated";
        }
     }
```

Comment: How does it not work? Do you get an error? Unexpected results? No results?

Comment: Wait, I think I see....

Comment: I suppose you're looking for GROUP BY.

Comment: Add some sample table data, and the expected result.

Comment: Could you explain why you COUNT `kind` when you fix `kind = 'Major'`. And I think the condition Exeded_houres should be > 120 not = 120

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/4064630/francis-lord  It return the alarm which is in the catch statment

Comment: @SweetGarl What error is thrown? (btw to tag a user just add @ in front of it's username like I did with yours)

Comment: @Francis Lord Connection Problem                                             catch (Exception er)
        {
            Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert('Connection problem');</script>");
        }

Comment: @SweetGarl what is in the exception? (In case you don't know how to see that, make a break point on the first line of the `Catch` block and hover over the `er` variable once the breakpoint is hit. Which Type is the exception and what is the message.

Comment: @ jarlh I use it thank you

Answer (score 0):

The `COUNT()` method will always return a value. Even if the 0, it will still return 1 row, which makes your `if` kind of useless since it will never reach the else part (`reader.HasRows == true` will always be true) instead, you should `ExecuteScalar()` right away and do the condition on the result.